# Find missing indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index

tool available to find missing indexes in mssql 2008 ? can we find the missing index using Database Engine Tuning Advisor

Comment: RE: " can we find the missing index using Database Engine Tuning Advisor"? Yes. That is one of its functions. You need to provide a workload for it to analyze though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server renders a handful of DVMs that can provide you with this information.  See the [TechNet reference on About the Missing Indexes Feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345524%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Mainly, you will be dealing with four DMVs:

- [sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345421%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- [sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345407%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- [sys.dm_db_missing_index_details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345434%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- [sys.dm_db_missing_index_columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345364%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Note: This is *how* you do it.  But be very careful when considering "missing indexes".  You could end up with a large amount of indexes and data manipulation will take a hit from that.  This does **not** replace prudent index consideration/creation.

Comment: Worth pointing out Glenn Berry's diagnostic scripts (http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/tag/dmv-queries/) and Aaron's **Don't just blindly create those "missing" indexes!** (http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/06/t-sql-queries/missing-index)

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to this have a look at Brent Ozar/Kendra Little's script sp_blitzindex.
You get a very nice report on the state of the indexes in your database.

Are there any missing, maybe there are a lot of indexes that are unused, a lot of heaps maybe?
All this is addressed and more in this report.

I use this frequently, copy the result to an excelsheet, make necessary changes, use color coding and add date of change. Then run it again a couple of weeks later and compare and so on. It is an easy way to get in to index tuning.

[BlitzIndex](http://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/) (Do not forget the video tutorial)

Do not forget that an unused index is maybe only used once a year and could be very important, dialogue with developers is key to success.